# ruby on rails coffeescript input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I'm using fullcalender in a rails app.
I have the following coffeescript code:

```
select: (start, end, allDay) ->
  title = prompt("Event Title:", "")
  hours = prompt("Hours", "")
  if title
  ...
```

Instead of using 2 prompt code lines, I'd like to have a small pop-up window with both data fields.  How should I accomplish it?  Should I use a Bootstrap modal?

Thanks

OK ---
I created this modal and it displays fine:

```
   <div id="calModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Create Labor</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-inline" method="get">
      <input type="text" id="title" class="input" placeholder="Title" name="title">
      <input type="floating" id="hours" class="input" placeholder="Hours" name="hours">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>`
```

But, the values for title and hours aren't usable in the rest of my coffeescript code:

```
   select: (start, end, allDay) ->
      $('#calModal').modal('show')
      title = $(".modal-body #title").val
      hours = $(".modal-body #hours").val
      if title
        $.create "/events/",
          event:
            title: title,
            starts_at: "" + start,
            ends_at: "" + end,
            all_day: allDay,
            workorder_id: 1,
            # need a modal for inputing these fields
            hours: hours,
            employee_id: 1
            # pickup the current employee
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`
```

These statements aren't working:

```
   title = $(".modal-body #title").val
   hours = $(".modal-body #hours").val
```

Comment: Modal dialog would work, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors with your code but the significant one is that you need to bind an event handler to the Save Changes button. Your code is expecting the value of #title and other fields to be there immediately after showing the modal and of course it won't be. An event handler on the Save Changes button should 1) close the modal 2) check the value of the form fields.

I had to add an id to the Save Changes button to easily reference it:

```
    <button id="savebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

and also found that you were using jQuery.val when you need to call jQuery.val() - i.e. call the method rather than just reference it

The following Coffeescript will open the modal on page load and then close the modal on clicking Save Changes and log the form field values to the Javascript console (I used coffeescript 1.3.1 as that is what I happened to have available)

```
$ ->
    $('#savebtn').bind 'click', (event) =>
        $("#calModal").modal('hide')
        title = $(".modal-body #title").val()
        hours = $(".modal-body #hours").val()
        console.log title
        console.log hours
        return


    $('#calModal').modal('show')
```

With the above snippet functioning, you should be able to get the rest of your code working.